# Moving a limit inside an integral over an infinite interval

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to prove that 
$\frac{d}{ds}\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{(\log x)^\ell}{x^s}dx = \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{d}{ds}\frac{(\log x)^\ell}{x^s}dx$, but it seems that my analysis skills are lacking. It is enough to show that the limit can pass under the integral in $\lim_{h \to 0}\left( \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{(\log x)^\ell}{x^{s+h}} - \frac{(\log x)^\ell}{x^{s}}\right)}{h}dx\right)$. From other questions here I got that the bounded convergence theorem should be used but for that the interval should be bounded, right? What should be used in this case then?

Comment: Do you know dominated convergence? Might be of some use.

Comment: @avid19 I looked it up but can't connect the dots...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is justified because
$$
\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{d}{ds}\frac{(\log x)^\ell}{x^s}\,dx
$$
converges uniformly on any interval $[a,b]\subset(1,\infty)$.

This is Proposition 9.7.5 in Elementary Classical Analysis by J. Marsden and M. Hoffman.

Comment: I don't understand "converges uniformly" in this context.

Comment: If $f\colon[a,\infty)\times[c,d]\to\mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_a^bf(x,y)\,dx=F(y)$ exists for all $y\in[c,d]$, $\int_a^infty f(x,y)\,dx$ is said to converge uniformly to $F$ on $[c,d]$ if for all $\epsilon>0$ there is a $b_0$ sucht that if  $b\ge b_0$ then $$\Bigl|\int_a^bf(x,y)\,dx-F(y)\Bigr|\le\epsilon\quad\forall y\in[c,d].$$